# Going to and Will - prediction

Tags: will-vs-going-to

Morning! I'm just wondering about a phrase that I've just seen. Can somebody help me?

In the sentence: "The train **will** leave at 11:45". I think that the speaker is saying something that he actually knows, so it's a prediction based on something he can see (or hear), right? So, shouldn't we use GOING TO instead of WILL?

Because I've read that WILL is for predictions based on our opinion. Am I misinterpreting?

Thanks!

Comment: There are various uses of _will_, as explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39850/in-depth-explanation-of-the-difference-between-will-and-going-to?rq=1). Here, it means 'is scheduled to'.

Comment: I think you are looking for a difference that doesn't really exist.   In modern US English at least, they are virtually interchangeable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between Going to and Will in Informal and Formal English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225942/differences-between-going-to-and-will-in-informal-and-formal-english)

Answer (score 2):

You are never *required* to use "going to." You can always use "will" instead of "going to," though it often sounds more formal. But the reverse isn't true: in some contexts, you can't use "going to" and need to use "will."

Incidentally, in this particular case native speakers would often use the simple present: "The train leaves at 11:45." *Edit:* This is because we often use the simple present to describe future events that occur at a known, scheduled time.

Comment: Mostly agreed, but I don't think the simple present is really used because the train *always* does that - [we use the simple present for a lot of scheduled events](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/), like "My plane lands in Paris at 8 PM tomorrow."

Comment: Good point, edited.

Comment: You are never "required" to use either one.

Comment: "Watch out! That dog **is going to** bite!" doesn't mean the same as "Watch out! That dog **will** bite!", so that's at least one context where you're "required" to use one or the other, depending on what you *mean*.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It's awesome have people to help English learners here!